# How to print function names using boost.stacktrace?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using [boost.stacktrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace.html) to print stacktraces of exceptions, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void bar() {
    throw std::runtime_error("A runtime error.");
}

void foo() {
    bar();
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled and executed it using the following command:

```
clang++ -g hello.cpp -ldl -lboost_stacktrace_backtrace -lbacktrace
./a.out
```

And I got the following result:

```
A runtime error.
 0# 0x000056335CB25570 in ./a.out
 1# __libc_start_main in /usr/lib/libc.so.6
 2# 0x000056335CB2534E in ./a.out
```

Not good, function names are replaced with addresses. What I want is something like this(which is shown in [boost.stacktrace's website](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html#stacktrace.getting_started.how_to_print_current_call_stack)):

```
0# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
1# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
2# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
3# bar(int) at /path/to/source/file.cpp:70
4# main at /path/to/main.cpp:93
5# __libc_start_main in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
6# _start
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please take note of the documentation regarding [configuration & build](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html).  You may also want to try disabling optimization when compiling your code.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for the suggestion. But I've already read [configuration & build](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html) before posting the question and tried various options specified in it, but still didn't achieve it, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: @G.M. I also tried disabling optimization using `-O0` with `g++`, didn't help either.

Comment: Hello @Searene, did you resolve it to see function name and line number? I am facing same problem in MSVC on WIndows

Comment: @PabitraDash No, I haven't solved it.

Comment: I think you need to compile and use `libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so` (or `.a`). If that doesn't exist in your Boost installation, you didn't follow the [configuration & build](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html) properly. That is not easy though! What made the trick for me is to call `bjam` with `cxxflags="-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this macro on your `.cpp` file

```
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
```

Then at compile, define this

```
-DBOOST_STACKTRACE_BACKTRACE_INCLUDE_FILE="</usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/backtrace.h>"
```

You can `ls /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to view which version you have. In my case, it was `9`